# Unable to read double or int after first adding second string

Tags: java, file, double

so I'm very very new to java and I'm having a slight problem. I'm adding various doubles and integers and trying to read data from a file, but when I try read data from the file after the second string, I am given an error. Anything before the second string is fine.

Here's my code;

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Assignment3 {

static Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {


Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("AssistantHoursAndRates.txt"));

    String Unit1 = inFile.nextLine();
    double NumberofAssistantsUnit1 = inFile.nextDouble();
    double Unit1Assistant1hours = inFile.nextDouble();
    double Unit1Assistant1rate = inFile.nextDouble();
    double Unit1Assistant2hours = inFile.nextDouble();
    double Unit1Assistant2rate = inFile.nextDouble();
    double Unit1Assistant3hours = inFile.nextDouble();
    double Unit1Assistant3rate = inFile.nextDouble();
    double Unit1Assistant4hours = inFile.nextDouble();
    double Unit1Assistant4rate = inFile.nextDouble();

    String Unit2 = inFile.nextLine();
    double NumberofAssistantsUnit2 = inFile.nextDouble();
```

I am given this error when I try read anything after the second string;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
at Assignment3.main(Assignment3.java:28)
```

I am unsure at to why I am receiving this error, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Here is the input file for those who were asking;

```
Unit One
4
32 8
38 6
38 6
16 7

Unit Two
0

Unit Three
2
36 7
36 7

Unit Four
6
32 6.5
32 6.5
36 6.5
36 6.5
38 6.5
38 6.5

Unit Five
4
32 6.5
32 8
32 7
32 8

Unit Six
5
38 7
30 6.5
24 8
24 8
24 8

Unit Seven
0

Unit Eight
1
40 12

Unit Nine
5
24 8
24 6.5
30 6.5
24 7
32 7
```

Comment: Might be that the file you're opening does not exist and thus `new Scanner(null)`?

Comment: Please mark the line the exception is referring to. Also, post the first few lines of the input file you are reading.

Comment: Show a snippet of the file. Starting from the beginning

Comment: Input file has been added

Comment: Before asking you should investigate yourself. When you don't know how to start just simplify your problem until you find out what step does the error go away and think about why. You have shown no investigation at all. Try removing blank lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you file looks like this

```
Unit1
10.00
40.00
15.00
40.00
15.00
40.00
15.00
40.00
15.00
Unit1
10.00
40.00
15.00
40.00
15.00
40.00
15.00
40.00
15.00
```

I just added an `inFile.nextLine()` after `double Unit1Assistant4rate = inFile.nextDouble();` and it works fine for me. Before I added it, I got the same Exception you did. But now it's fine.

```
    String Unit1 = inFile.nextLine();
    double NumberofAssistantsUnit1 = inFile.nextDouble();
    double Unit1Assistant1hours = inFile.nextDouble();
    double Unit1Assistant1rate = inFile.nextDouble();
    double Unit1Assistant2hours = inFile.nextDouble();
    double Unit1Assistant2rate = inFile.nextDouble();
    double Unit1Assistant3hours = inFile.nextDouble();
    double Unit1Assistant3rate = inFile.nextDouble();
    double Unit1Assistant4hours = inFile.nextDouble();
    double Unit1Assistant4rate = inFile.nextDouble();

    inFile.nextLine();

    String Unit2 = inFile.nextLine();
    double NumberofAssistantsUnit2 = inFile.nextDouble();
    double Unit2Assistant1hours = inFile.nextDouble();
    double Unit2Assistant1rate = inFile.nextDouble();
    double Unit2Assistant2hours = inFile.nextDouble();
    double Unit2Assistant2rate = inFile.nextDouble();
    double Unit2Assistant3hours = inFile.nextDouble();
    double Unit2Assistant3rate = inFile.nextDouble();
    double Unit2Assistant4hours = inFile.nextDouble();
    double Unit2Assistant4rate = inFile.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("This works fine");
```

Before I added the `inFile.nextLine()`. The exception pointed to this line `double NumberofAssistantsUnit2 = inFile.nextDouble();`. So I assumed the first part of code worked. It's just when the program tried to read the the second set of text, the `String Unit2 = inFile.nextLine();` ate up the empty space after the `nextDouble()` as the String. So the next line would be `Unit2` instead of the `double` you were expecting. This happens when combining the reading of `String`s and other value types. I prefer to read line by line and split, to avoid this problem.

**Edit after OP edit with file**

Try this code out. It's Runnable. Works for me. Just replace the file name

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment3 {

    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader("aptunits.txt"));

        int unit = 1;
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);

            double total = 0;

            int assistants = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Number of Assistants " + assistants);
            System.out.println("Hours  Rate");
            System.out.println("------------");
            for (int i = 0; i < assistants; i++) {
                int hours = input.nextInt();
                System.out.print(hours + "     ");
                double rate = input.nextDouble();
                System.out.println(rate);               
                total += (hours * rate);
            }
            System.out.println("Total cost of Unit " + unit + " is " + total);
            System.out.println();
            unit++;

            if (input.hasNextLine()) {
                input.nextLine();
                input.next();
            }

        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the method you suggested but still received the error. My input file is slightly different from the example you gave, I have added it above.

Answer (score 0):

The input file in the question has two non-numeric lines between the last number for Unit One and the first number for Unit Two. You need to do two nextLine() calls to skip both of those.

```
inFile.nextLine();
String Unit2 = inFile.nextLine();
```