# Storing totals from a loop as doubles

Tags: java, arrays, input, double

I'm currently looking for a way to store totals from calculation of values taken from an input file that are worked out in a loop. I am trying to figure out a way to store the totals as doubles so I can take a user input from the console and compare the totals with the input. Here is my code so far;

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment3 {

static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader("AssistantHoursAndRates.txt"));

    double UnitRM;
    System.out.println("Enter recommended maximum staff cost of Unit 1");
        UnitRM = console.nextDouble ();
            System.out.println("Recommended maximum staff cost of Unit1 = "+UnitRM);

            System.out.println("         ");

    int unit = 1;
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);

        double total = 0;

        int assistants = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Number of Assistants " + assistants);
        System.out.println("Hours  Rate");
        System.out.println("------------");
        for (int i = 0; i < assistants; i++) {
            int hours = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print(hours + "     ");
            double rate = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println(rate);               
            total += (hours * rate);
        }


System.out.println("Total cost of Unit " + unit + " is " + total);
System.out.println();
    unit++;



        if (input.hasNextLine()) {
            input.nextLine();
            input.next();





          }

      } 
  }

}
```

Here is the input file if needed;

```
Unit One
4
32 8
38 6
38 6
16 7

Unit Two
0

Unit Three
2
36 7
36 7

Unit Four
6
32 6.5
32 6.5
36 6.5
36 6.5
38 6.5
38 6.5

Unit Five
4
32 6.5
32 8
32 7
32 8

Unit Six
5
38 7
30 6.5
24 8
24 8
24 8

Unit Seven
0

Unit Eight
1
40 12

Unit Nine
5
24 8
24 6.5
30 6.5
24 7
32 7
```

A friend of mine recommended using arrays, any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Code as it currently is;

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment3 {

static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader("AssistantHoursAndRates.txt"));

    double UnitRM1;
        System.out.println("Enter recommended maximum staff cost of Unit 1");
            UnitRM1 = console.nextDouble ();
                System.out.println("Recommended maximum staff cost of Unit1 = "+UnitRM1);

                System.out.printf("%10s\n", " ");

    double UnitRM2;
            System.out.println("Enter recommended maximum staff cost of Unit 2");
                UnitRM2 = console.nextDouble ();
                    System.out.println("Recommended maximum staff cost of Unit2 = "+UnitRM2);

                    System.out.printf("%10s\n", " ");

    double UnitRM3;
            System.out.println("Enter recommended maximum staff cost of Unit 3");       
                UnitRM3 = console.nextDouble ();        
                    System.out.println("Recommended maximum staff cost of Unit3 = "+UnitRM3);   

                    System.out.printf("%10s\n", " ");

    double UnitRM4;
            System.out.println("Enter recommended maximum staff cost of Unit 4");
                UnitRM4 = console.nextDouble ();
                    System.out.println("Recommended maximum staff cost of Unit4 = "+UnitRM4);   

                    System.out.printf("%10s\n", " ");

     double UnitRM5;            
             System.out.println("Enter recommended maximum staff cost of Unit 5");      
                UnitRM5 = console.nextDouble ();        
                    System.out.println("Recommended maximum staff cost of Unit5 = "+UnitRM5);   

                    System.out.printf("%10s\n", " ");

     double UnitRM6;            
             System.out.println("Enter recommended maximum staff cost of Unit 6");              
                UnitRM6 = console.nextDouble ();       
                    System.out.println("Recommended maximum staff cost of Unit6 = "+UnitRM6);

                    System.out.printf("%10s\n", " ");

     double UnitRM7;
             System.out.println("Enter recommended maximum staff cost of Unit 7");
                UnitRM7 = console.nextDouble ();
                    System.out.println("Recommended maximum staff cost of Unit7 = "+UnitRM7);

                    System.out.printf("%10s\n", " ");

     double UnitRM8;            
             System.out.println("Enter recommended maximum staff cost of Unit 8");      
                UnitRM8 = console.nextDouble ();        
                    System.out.println("Recommended maximum staff cost of Unit8 = "+UnitRM8);   

                    System.out.printf("%10s\n", " ");

     double UnitRM9;                
            System.out.println("Enter recommended maximum staff cost of Unit 9");               
               UnitRM9 = console.nextDouble ();     
                   System.out.println("Recommended maximum staff cost of Unit9 = "+UnitRM9);




    double[] totals = new double[9];        
    int unit = 1;
    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);

        double total = 0;

        int assistants = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Number of Assistants " + assistants);
        System.out.println("Hours  Rate");
        System.out.println("------------");
        for (int i = 0; i < assistants; i++) {
            int hours = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print(hours + "     ");
            double rate = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println(rate);               
            total += (hours * rate);
        }


System.out.println("Total cost of Unit " + unit + " is " + total);
System.out.println();   
totals[unit - 1] = total;
    unit++;



        if (input.hasNextLine()) {
            input.nextLine();
            input.next();



        } 


    }


        System.out.println("Comparisons are as follows;");       

    }


}
```

Error given;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at Assignment3.main(Assignment3.java:108)
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code?

Comment: If you simply need help with how to declare an array, take a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) for an example, or is there some other issue I am missing?

Comment: At the moment nothing is wrong with the code, it's working perfectly. I'm just looking for a way to store the totals given from the calculations so I can use them in comparison with user input from the console

Comment: You haven't really added anything new to this assignment since the answer was given to you from [This same assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311831/unable-to-read-double-or-int-after-first-adding-second-string/20312197#20312197)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `double` array to hold the totals

```
double[] totals = new double[9];  // all the totals are stored here
unit = 1;
...

while(input.hasNextLine()){
    ...
    ...

    totals[unit - 1] = total;
    unit++;
}
```

Comment: For the second line `Unit = 1;`, is that representing the unit for each index?

Comment: That's the code you already have. The reason I created it for you was to use it to print the unit number. But you can also use it as the array index. But since arrays start at 0, when I started adding values to the `total[]` array, I started at index `unit - 1`

Comment: Ahh right okay, so do I have to use the while loop again to collect the totals in the array? Sorry to be a bother, I'm very new to this

Comment: No you don't. My answer is pretty much a hint to where you need to place the variables that dont already exist. `unit = 1` exists. `unit++;` exists.

Comment: I'm still a little confused on which variables to add, which variables should I be looking to add?

Comment: In your code, you have `int unit = 1` and in the loop you have `unit++`. Look at my answer. Add what's not already in your code.

Comment: All this does is gives you an array. You still need to do some implementation to compare the values from the array with the user input.

Comment: Okay I understand now. So I've added the variables and added code to take all the necessary user input and the totals are being held in the array. When I go to begin the comparisons bellow the final `if` statement, it just takes it back into the loop, how do I close the loop to begin the comparisons after everything else?

Comment: The array is declared outside the loop. So you dont need to perform the comparisons inside the loop. You can do it after the loop.

Comment: What I mean is when I try write another line at the very bottom of the code, such as `System.out.println("Comparisons are as follows;");` it adds the line to the loop instead of separate and after the loop.

Comment: What do you mean it adds the line to the loop? You mean it prints out multiple times?

Comment: If your code is outside of the loop, it shouldn't print multiple times.

Comment: Yeah it's printed multiple times between each set of unit variables, even when the code is at the very end after the `if` statement. I'm guessing I've missed something and I'm not outside the loop?

Comment: If you indent your code properly, you should see where the loop ends.

Comment: The closing bracket of the loop is the third from the bottom. I'm sorry, but if you don't even know these basic, it's hard for anyone to help you.

Comment: I know this, but when I add the line after the closing bracket, the line isn't displayed and I'm given an exception relating to the `if` statement. Like I said, I'm new to this and have been thrown into the deep end. I'm just trying to learn, I don't mean to be a bother.

Comment: Count the closing brackets at the bottom. one.. two.. Then place your code above that.

Comment: That's where the code is, but nothing is printed and an error is shown (check question for error).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to print? Why don't you update your code. This guessing is ridiculous.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the placement of that last line. And what in the world are you expecting this to print out? `System.out.printf("%10s\n", " ");`

Comment: It's just to space out the lines so the console is easier to read

Comment: Okay, well I really appreciate all your help so far.

Answer (score 0):

I personally think that your code looks good, but there is one line that I noticed would kind of mess up in some situations.

```
System.out.println("         ");
```

This is very inefficient, considering that you have to physically space everything. For example, if your data was to change, your spacing would eventually be off. Not to mention you would have to constantly space out :D. There is a better way of doing this:

```
System.out.printf("%9s\n", " ");
```

This will print out 9 spaces as if you had hit the space bar 9 times.

Hope it helps!